# getting sbt : Depends: java6-runtime-headless while trying to install SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

Hi I am trying to install sbt.
I have Oracle Java installed (not openJDK):

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

But when I try to install SBT I am getting this:

```
sudo apt-get install sbt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sbt : Depends: java6-runtime-headless
       Recommends: git
 scala : Depends: java6-runtime-headless
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**EDIT:**
got the same response when using

> apt-get -f install sbt

Comment: Have you tried running apt-get -f install?

Comment: @znurgl yes, got the same response

Comment: This is really more of a question about your specific linux distro than it is about sbt or scala.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says:

```
apt-get -f install
```

'f' means 'fix broken', because something wrong with your current package repo

'apt-get -f install sbt' is wrong!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend skipping the .deb install of `sbt` and `scala` and just installing sbt manually as per http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Manual-Installation.html

Then for interactive scala play, just use `./sbt console`

This makes it easy to play with different versions of scala by simply having directories with different sbt project files.

Answer (score 0):

I had [remove scala](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/universe/s/scala/uninstall/index.html) 
and then install java8 installer following [this instructions](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/install-oracle-java-6-7-or-8-ubuntu-14-04/)